# Collapsing constant regions of path

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $f: [0,1] \to X$ be some continuous map ($X$ some topological space).
Let introduce the equivalence relation on $[0,1]$
$y \sim_c z \iff $ $f$ constant on $[y,z]$ (or on $[z,y]$ if $z < y$) 
Is the space $[0,1]/\sim_c$ with quotient topology homeomorphic to some interval [a,b]?
And for which topological spaces $X$ is this true?

Comment: what do you think about this?

Comment: then there are a finite number of such bad regions this is true by mathematical induction (we paste finite number of intervals). But when there are infinite many such regions I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true iff $X$ is a $T_1$ space: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109333/58818 for a proof of the hard direction (that $T_1$ spaces have the desired property).

Let us show that if $X$ is not $T_1$, then there is a continuous function $f\colon I\to X$ such that the quotient $X/\!\sim_c$ is not homeomorphic to an interval. The idea is basically to find a sort of copy of the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) within such $X$.

Since $X$ is not $T_1$, there are $a\neq b$ such that every neighbourhood of $b$ contains $a$.

Let $f\colon[0,1]\to X$ be given by
$$f(t)=\begin{cases}b&\text{ if }t\leq 1/2\\a&\text{ if }t>1/2\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is continuous, and there are precisely two $\sim_c$-equivalence classes: $[0,1/2]$ and $(1/2,1]$. This means that the quotient $X/\!\sim_c$ has precisely two points, and is immediatelly not homeomorphic to an interval.

(In fact, the open sets in this quotient are only $X/\!\sim_c$, $\varnothing$ and $\left\{(1/2,1]\right\}$  (it is another copy of the Sierpinski space), and it is not even Hausdorff.)